# Cannot boot LiveUSB with X1 Yoga

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb, thinkpad

I recently bought a `ThinkPad X1 Yoga` and I'm trying to install Ubuntu in dual boot alongside Windows 10.

I installed Windows 10 from USB easily. But when I try to boot Ubuntu from USB, the computer just gets stuck.

Here is what I tried:

1. Tried to create the USB with different tools (`Unetbootin`, `Universal USB Installer`, ...)
2. I checked my BIOS settings and I have

   - UEFI/Legacy Boot [Both]
   - UEFI/Legacy Boot Priority [Legacy First]
   - Secure Boot [Disabled]
   - USB UEFI BIOS Support [Enabled]
3. I also tried Ubuntu GNome or Kubuntu

With everything I tried, the behavior is always the same. First, I make the computer boot from USB. Then a first screen does appear (depending on what I used to create the USB) that allows me to choose between `Try without installation`, `Install`, etc...
And when I choose `Try without installation`, the computer gets stuck at the same screen, the CPU goes into high usage but nothing happens, it remains stuck.

One last thing I didn't try is to use a USB 3.0 stick (I only have 2.0 sticks and my computer has only 3.0 ports), but I'm not sure it would help.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try live linux installer doing from windows.  There are problems with legacy.  This does the trick.  I prefer no uefi these days.  Dual boot is more easy this way.  Otherwise windows takes over the whole machine.

Comment: Try to pass the intel_pstate=disable option to the kernel on boot. See the bugreport here: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=110941

Comment: @M.Luethi thank you for your answer. I did come across this intel_pstate already while researching, it might be it, but I never worked with kernel parameters. Could you please explain to me how exactly I could add this parameter for my live USB kernel, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: @Worx I installed Arch Linux, so I am not sure whether it works the same way. It seems to be explained here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I eventually found the problem, in fact @M.Luethi was right, `intel_pstate` was causing this.

So, in the boot screen, instead of directly launching Linux, I pressed 'e' to edit the command before executing. At the end of it, I added `intel_pstate=disable` and it worked fine afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

First set the UEFI/Legacy **Boot Priority** in BIOS to **UEFI First**.

Boot Windows and create the USB using the `diskpart` tool.

Open command prompt as administrator and execute :

```
diskpart
list disk  
select disk *  
clean  
create partition primary  
active  
format fs=fat32 quick  
assign letter=**
```

Note: `*` = number of USB drive | `**` = select a free drive letter

Mount the ISO image and copy the whole content to the USB drive.

Change the boot order in BIOS to boot from USB - then install Ubuntu.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, I followed every step, however the exact same problem happened. Note that if I try to same USB on my old computer, it works fine, so it must be something wrong with my new one.